# How to set up a realistic dry grass (hay) shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, photorealism

So this is the node setup:

[image]
 I have been following the Grass Field tutorial by Gleb Alexandrov, found here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eshOzshjt90 .

But I cant get the grass to look straw yellow and end up making it look red / redish green (by changing the RGB value).

I need it to look like this:

[image]

I am open any other solutions as well, I just need it to look photo-realistic.

PS: I have used a hair-particle system for the grass field.

Comment: That image is not photo-realistic. It has been tinted with a lot of yellow and some red. [img]https://i.imgur.com/LotL3ta.jpg[/img]